# Integrating $\int_0^{\exp(-x^2)}\ln (1+t)\cos(t^3)\;dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

$$\int_0^{\exp(-x^2)}\ln (1+t)\cos(t^3)\;dt$$

Will this be done via Feynman trick? If so, please show how. I am new to the trick.

Also, I was given the tip to use the first theorem of calulus.

Comment: Are you supposed to take its derivative? That's usually when fundamental theorem of calculus applies.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see the trick to be used.

Since $e^{-x^2}$ is small, I should try a Taylor series for the integrand. This would be
$$\log(1+t)\cos^3(x)=t-\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{3}-\frac{t^4}{4}+\frac{t^5}{5}-\frac{t^6}{6}-\frac{5
   t^7}{14}+\frac{t^8}{8}+O\left(t^9\right)$$
$$\int\log(1+t)\cos^3(x)=\frac{t^2}{2}-\frac{t^3}{6}+\frac{t^4}{12}-\frac{t^5}{20}+\frac{t^6}{30}-\frac{t^7}
   {42}-\frac{5 t^8}{112}+\frac{t^9}{72}+O\left(t^{10}\right)$$ which is quite accurate as shown below for six significant figures
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
x & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 0.0 & 0.345437 & 0.343580\\
 0.1 & 0.341538 & 0.339782 \\
 0.2 & 0.329312 & 0.327851 \\
 0.3 & 0.307856 & 0.306827 \\
 0.4 & 0.277291 & 0.276696 \\
 0.5 & 0.239591 & 0.239315 \\
 0.6 & 0.198222 & 0.198120 \\
 0.7 & 0.157032 & 0.157002 \\
 0.8 & 0.119212 & 0.119204 \\
 0.9 & 0.0867863 & 0.0867850 \\
 1.0 & 0.0606069 & 0.0606066 \\
 1.1 & 0.0405984 & 0.0405984 \\
 1.2 & 0.0260805 & 0.0260805 \\
 1.3 & 0.0160637 & 0.0160637 \\
 1.4 & 0.00948501 & 0.00948501 \\
 1.5 & 0.00536903 & 0.00536903 \\
 1.6 & 0.00291386 & 0.00291386 \\
 1.7 & 0.00151652 & 0.00151652 \\
 1.8 & 0.000757085 & 0.000757085 \\
 1.9 & 0.000362646 & 0.000362646 \\
 2.0 & 0.000166717 & 0.000166717
\end{array}
\right)$$